# A subspace $Y$ of a Banach space $X$ is complete iff the set $Y$ is closed in $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

> A subspace $Y$ of a Banach space $X$ is complete iff the set $Y$ is
> closed in $X$.

Proof:⇒)  If $x\in\mathrm{cl}(Y)$ there exists a sequence $x_
n$ in Y which converges to x and **as a consquence is a Cauchy sequence (in $X$ and $Y$)**. But Y is complete, so xn converges in Y to a point $x′$. According to the uniqueness of the limit, $x=x′\in Y$. That is, $cl(Y)\subset Y$ and hence, $Y$ is closed.

⇐) Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. The limit $x$ of $x_n$ exists in $X$ because $X$ is complete. As $Y$ is complete, contains all its limit points, so $x\in Y$ and so, $Y$ is complete.

It may be obvious but i'm not getting **Why $x_n$ is a cauchy sequence??**

Comment: $\|x_n-x_m\| \le \|x_n-x\| + \|x_m -x\|$, hence if $x_n \to x$, we see that $x_n$ is Cauchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basic metric space theory.  Suppose $x_n\to x$.  Given $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\|x_n-x\|<\varepsilon/2$ for $n\geq N$.  Then for $n,m\geq N$ we have 
$$\|x_n-x_m\|\leq\|x_n-x\|+\|x-x_m\|<\varepsilon.$$
Therefore the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.